# How do I connect a database to the Dockerfile example for Drupal 7?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm brand new to Docker and am trying to set up a Drupal 7 installation.

I ran [this example](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/9e1ff6c719c7a6dec88b1089f9128dab428c4eed/7/Dockerfile)

```
# from https://www.drupal.org/requirements/php#drupalversions
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

# install the PHP extensions we need
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release
ENV DRUPAL_VERSION 7.41
ENV DRUPAL_MD5 7636e75e8be213455b4ac7911ce5801f

RUN curl -fSL "http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-${DRUPAL_VERSION}.tar.gz" -o drupal.tar.gz \
    && echo "${DRUPAL_MD5} *drupal.tar.gz" | md5sum -c - \
    && tar -xz --strip-components=1 -f drupal.tar.gz \
    && rm drupal.tar.gz \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data sites
```

but I get this error when trying to connect to a database.

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the
>   following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.

Do I need to run a MySQL container as well? I don't fully understand how containers "talk to one another", ie. if I used the [MySQL example](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ac05512a1b788e8ae658d0f4a980ff7a01a51c93/5.5/Dockerfile) how would I tell my Drupal container to use that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is best to tun the drupal image directly, instead of its Dockerfile.
See the [Drupal Full Description](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/).

```
$ docker run --name some-drupal -p 8080:80 -d drupal
```

> Then, access it via http://localhost:8080 or http://host-ip:8080 in a browser.

For using it with a database, you need to run a database container first, [like mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

Then you can link it to a drupal container:

```
$ docker run --name some-drupal --link some-mysql:mysql -d drupal
```